# Chat room for Stats

Tags: discussion

For some strange reason no one has made it before, so here it is:
http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170/stats
Probably it is a better place for our discussions than comments.

Comment: Your question looks like a chat discussion, seems you have spend too much time chatting  :) I think you should rephrase it with something like
"Definition of aims and rules for the use of the chat room"

Comment: @robin It was meant as an ad, so I admit that this is not a real question.

Answer (score 1):

This could be useful.

One thing that we could do is to have "office hours" for the moderators to be online at certain times/days (for short time periods).  That would give others specific times to join the chat.

Comment: Office hrs is a cool idea.