# Statistics Chat Room

Tags: support, chat

A quick search for "chat" in the questions turns up [this](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322/chat-room-for-stats). But from what I interpret this is for meta-discussion. So, is there a chat room for [stats](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)? If not, can there be? I don't see a link at the top of the page (image stolen from [Stack Overflow FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)):

[image: The Notifications Bar]

**Update:** This is the top of my page. Is there something I am missing?

[image: My Notifications Bar]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be links at the top *and* bottom of each screen:

[image: top line]

[image: bottom line]

If you're still stuck, navigate to http://chat.stackexchange.com/.

### Edit

An unfortunate "feature" of the current SE interface is that the "chat" link on the top bar is temporarily replaced by a "blog" link whenever a new blog article is posted.  (Don't get me going on how confusing it is to users when their interface morphs around...)  This appears to be the cause of this question.  Please note, though, that the *bottom* links have been constant and do not seem to come and go in the same way: chat has always been available there.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: @Why: updated the reply :-).